# Create Azure Maps with Real Time Live Geo Coordinates

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-api-apps, azure-maps

I'm trying to develop a JS web application with `Azure Maps` to show the location / marker based on the Geo-coordinates received dynamically i.e., every few seconds we receive the geo-coordinates externally through rest calls.

The idea is to pass the geo-coordinates (through JSON) to the Azure Maps application and every time update the location of the marker on the Azure Map. Kind of simulating the Real Time tracking.

I've referred through the Official Azure Maps documentations and sample codes. However I couldn't find a suitable example to determine whether the above mentioned scenario is feasible (to develop) with Azure Maps. Kindly suggest the scope of developing the scenario using Azure Maps.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty straight forward scenario that has a few different ways that can be done. As you mentioned, the first part is that you will need to create a REST service to get the data from the server to the frontend app which can then be used by the map. The architecture would depend on the number of items you are tracking and the update frequency. Updating once every few seconds is fairly easy to support.

For the REST service there are two paths to choose from;

- A pull model where you have some code that calls the service every X seconds and retrieves all the updated data. This is fairly easy code up and easy to limit the update frequency
- A push model where you have a stream / web socket that stays open and constantly sends updates. This allows for updates to be sent to the front end faster as there is no waiting between update requests. This is a bit more work to achieve, SignalR is a good option.

Once you have data on the front end, updating the position of the data on the map can be done in a few ways.

- If you have the data for all locations, simply replace all data in the data source you are using in the map with the new data (use the setData function as it will remove and replace all data in the data source with a single re-render of the map).
- If you are only sending updates for a subset of your items, then you would need all items to have a unique ID which you can use to retrieve the shapes from the data source and update their position value in the data source. The data source class has a getShapeById method. If you have a lot of items to update, it would be more efficient to get the JSON of all the data in the data source, then loop through all items and update the required items as needed, then passing the edited JSON into the setShapes function.

In Azure Maps, data is stored in a data source, and a data source is connected to one or more rendering layers. This means you only need to update data in the data source and it will automatically refresh the map accordingly.

This is a decent tutorial if you are leveraging Azure IoT for monitoring the movement of your items: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-iot-hub-maps

Here is another good code sample: https://github.com/Azure/iot-workshop-asset-tracking